Retrieve JIRA issues in Apex using JIRA's Rest API
So I am trying to retrieve output of JQL query using in Apex using API provided by Jira.
However I am not able to format my body such that I receive the expected output in JSON file.
here is my code
public class JiraRestClient {

  private static final String JIRA_BASE_URL = 'https://sregmi48.atlassian.net';
  private static final String JIRA_API_TOKEN = 'my_api_code';

  public static HttpResponse getAllIssues(string jqlQuery) {
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(JIRA_BASE_URL + '/rest/api/3/search');
    request.setMethod('POST');  // Use GET for searching issues by project key
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf('apiToken:' + JIRA_API_TOKEN)));
    request.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
      
    Map<String, Object> requestBodyMap = new Map<String, Object>{
        'jql' => jqlQuery
    };
    String requestBodyJSON = JSON.serialize(requestBodyMap);      
//  String requestBody = '{"jql":{"project":{"key":"' + projectKey + '"}}}';
    request.setBody(requestBodyJSON);
    
      
    System.debug(requestBodyJSON);  

    return new Http().send(request);
  }
}

Executing this code in the Anonymous window with
HttpResponse response = JiraRestClient.getAllIssues('project = "JIR"');
if (response.getStatusCode() == 415) {
String responseBody = response.getBody();
System.debug('Response Body: ' + responseBody);

List<String> responseHeaders = response.getHeaderKeys();
for (String key : responseHeaders) {

        System.debug('Response Header ' + key );
    }

} else {
String responseBody = response.getBody();
System.debug('Response Body: ' + responseBody);
}

However, I don't get any value in my JSON file.
And troubleshooting the issue shows that my response body format is not supported.

How do I solve this problem?

step 1: get this working in your favorite command-line or web-based API client. Step 2: port to Apex.

could you give me some reference for Step 2?

Step 2: copy all headers, body, et cetera from your successful call to Apex.

Hey, I set everything like you said. However, I am encountering the status code 405 'Client Must be Authorised to Access the Resource' error. I am the one who created those Projects in JIRA and yet I am not able to access the the project from Apex.

Please edit your question and show a successful call from another client, let's compare that to Apex.
